# Meteor keydown doesn't work

Tags: jquery, meteor, keydown

I am using meteor to update a document in the database. However keydown does not seem to be working. here is the code.

```
Template.leaderboard.events({
    'keydown button.inc': function(evt) {
        if (evt.which === 39) {
            Players.update(Session.get("character"), {$inc: {score: 20}});
        }

        Players.update(Session.get("character"), {$inc: {score: 20}});
        //Players.update(Session.get("character"), {$set: {name: 'images/characters/ninja.png'}});
    },
    'keydown': function(evt) {
        if (evt.which === 37) {
            Players.update(Session.get("character"), {$inc: {score: -20}});
            //Players.update(Session.get("character"), {$set: {name: 'images/characters/ninjaleft.png'}});
        }
        Players.update(Session.get("character"), {$inc: {score: -20}});
    }
});
```

Why isn't my keydown working?

Comment: What is it that does not work? Is the event not firing at all? Are you having trouble listening to certain button events? Please be a bit more specific.

Comment: Could you throw in a console.log there to see if its firing? Do you have any errors in your js console if you type something? & is your Session hash set?

Comment: @seldon the keydown event wont work at all.

Comment: @akshat i put a console.log in there and nothing happens. maybe this is happening because meteor is still new.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I've had success attaching keyboard events to textareas and inputs, like the following:

```
Template.inputArea.events({
  'keydown textarea' : function(e){
     console.log(e.which);
  }
});
```

I'm not quite as familiar with attaching keyboard events to other DOM elements. I know for `window` events, I've had to use jQuery to attach keydown inputs.

```
Template.foo.rendered = function(){
  $(window).on('keydown', function(e){
    console.log(e.which);
  });
};

// and on newer versions 

Template.foo.onRendered( function() {
    $(window).on('keydown', function(e){
        console.log(e.which);
    });
});
```

Perhaps you could try something like that...

Comment: As of this writing the keydown is triggered just fine on any kind of element. I don't think the jQuery event listener workaround is needed.